# create sharepoint “one” alert on more than “one” list

Tags: alert, list

iS it possible to create a sharepoint alert that sends notifications from 2 lists or more??
(to send all notifications in one email)

Comment: i need help fo r this as well. Can someone please explain in more detail? Thanks,
Ninel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on James's idea, the best way to do this would be to create an Alert list which takes an items url, the title and change type and set a daily/weekly alert on that.

On all your other lists create a simple workflow on change/create/delete that adds an item to the Alert list you created and assigns the appropriate information ( url, title, change type etc) to that list item.

You will then receive only one email alert.

Answer (score 1):

You could trigger the alert from within a workflow that is attached to a content type which is associated to more than one list.

Answer (score 1):

Create a search on your target set of lists and set the alert on that search on search results page.